# Other possible pykrete like, ice based alloys?

Tags: science-based, materials

Pykrete is composed of sawdust and water and as a result freezes at 28 F, are there any other solutes or materials with which one can make ice alloys?

I was wondering if there were any cheap easy to find materials that could be used as a substitute for sawdust that would in fact form an alloy with a much higher/or lower melting and freezing point, especially one that is extremely cheap?

Comment: I will repeat myself: read the tag description. You keep using tags which are not supposed to be standalone in a standalone way

Comment: I think you mean "composite" not "alloy".

Comment: Mythbusters experimented with this and found that a variety of frozen wet newspaper was even tougher and even more resistant to gunfire, so you might want to check that out and what they say about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pykrete isn't an alloy; it's a composite, like steel-reinforced concrete, resin-impregnated carbon fiber, or fiberglass. Ice is a binder that holds wood fibers in place, while the wood fibers contribute tensile strength and toughness, and reduce the thermal conductivity of the bulk material, making it harder to melt.

Lowering the melting point is easy; changing out the fiber portion of a composite material won't do much for you in that regard, but if you want it to melt more easily for some reason, just add salt. Or alcohol. Or ammonia.

Raising the melting point is considerably harder. You could probably do it by introducing a gas, like methane, CO2, or xenon to form a clathrate hydrate. But eve those don't have melting points that are really significantly above 0C unless you also put them under pressure; at 50 atmospheres, the melting point of CO2 clathrate hydrate only goes up to 8C. Maybe you could do something like pre-stressed concrete, though, and use a high tension wrapping material to keep cells of the ice under compression?

If you just want alternative fiber options, they are numerous. Sawdust just happens to be plentiful and cheap. You could just as well use textile fibers, or carbon fiber, or stainless steel wool--steel would probably increase rather than decrease the bulk thermal conductivity, though.

Comment: [30C as a melting point](https://www.quora.com/What-substances-increase-the-melting-point-of-ice)?

Answer (score 0):

**Asbestos.**

Working backwards - wood is basically cellulose.  I consider nonwood cellulose (e.g. hemp, cotton) to be wood for these purposes.  Cellulose offers lots of hydrophilic OH molecules to interact with the water and with each other and the cellulose itself is a polymer.  I think those aspects must account for the ability of wood to fortify ice although Kearsley's answer provides another take on it.   If it is the hydrogen bonding with water that is needed, what is another cheap, durable polymer that has lots of hydrophilic side chains but that is not a polymeric carbon sugar?

[image: asbestos]

https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/chemistry/chrysotile

Asbestos fits the bill.  It is a mineral polymer, available and cheap with loads of available oxygen to participate in bonds with water.  I wondered if anyone had ever tried fortifying ice with asbestos.  It turns out yes!

[COLLOIDAL ASBESTOS FIBRILS
AS REINFORCEMENTS FOR
POLYMERIC STRUCTURES](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19670026685/downloads/19670026685.pdf)  NASA 1967

> We have found that structure strength depends greatly on the chemical
> nature of the polymeric matrix. Matrix materials well suited to
> asbestos  reinforcement include phenolic resins and polymers
> containing free carboxyl  groups. We have also found that ice is
> greatly reinforced by asbestos.  Little or no strengthening by
> asbestos has been found in the following  matrixes: nylon,
> polypropylene, polyurethanes, and gelatin.

Table 2 in the linked document compares the various polymers they augmented with asbestos.  I was impressed that the tensile strength of ice was negligible but asbestos fortified ice had a tensile strength comparable to polyester!

They dispersed the asbestos fibers using soap, and residual soap weakened the various fortified products which I take as support for the idea that it is the hydrophilic bonds that are responsible for the effect.

Comment: Wood is basically [lignin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lignin). *Grass* (or, if you prefer, straw) is basically cellulose. One is strong and tough, the other isn't.

Comment: @AlexP :  lignin is there but a minor player.  Wood is mostly cellulose and hemicellulose.  /There are two major chemical components in wood: lignin (18–
35%) and carbohydrate (65– 75%)./  https://www.fpl.fs.fed.us/documnts/pdf1984/pette84a.pdf   In exchange for this beneficial enlightenment, maybe you can do something about that pesky downvote.